# What exactly was in the redacted document about Skye from Agents of Shield Season 1?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

We know that Coulson won't tell her the truth, but I can't remember what the document actually ends up saying? Did it provide different info than the ex-SHIELD agent Coulson and May picked up for interviewing?

Comment: Wasn't that the file about Skye getting dropped off as a baby by a SHIELD agent, and the village that was destroyed where they found her, etc?

Comment: Was that the document or the ex-agent? Or both?

Comment: It was about how ███████████ █████ to █████████ when ██████ ████ ██████████, because ██████ ██████ ██████████ and █████ ██████████.

Comment: Could someone please tell me how to read @KSmarts's comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The redacted document seen on-screen was an internal SHIELD memo detailing the results of a medical exam performed on baby Skye at the orphanage**.

The letterhead on the page leads us to believe it was written from within St. Agnes Orphanage, indicating that at least one SHIELD agent was undercover at the orphanage to keep tabs on Skye.

There were apparently other pages contained in the file (at least one of which apparently identified the gender of the agent who delivered Skye to the orphanage), but the medical results memo is the only document shown on-screen:

[image]

Comment: So we never learn what exactly Coulson learned from the document but couldn't bring himself to tell Skye?

Comment: @gannawag I could be wrong, but I think that was the part he told May at the end of the same episode - that the agent who took Skye to the orphanage (and whom Skye believed was possibly her mother at the time) was murdered afterwards.